# Better/faster way to fill a big array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

I have 3 *.dat files (346KB,725KB,1762KB) that are filled with a json-string of "big" int-Arrays.

Each time my object is created (several times) I take those three files and use  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize the arrays into the object.

I thought about using binary-files instead of a json-string or could I even save these arrays directly? I dont need to use these files, it's just the location the data is currently saved. I would gladly switch to anything faster.

**What are the different ways to speed up the initialization of these objects?**

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking for - could you show us your existing code, and then we can try to work out how to improve it?

Comment: How data is stored exactly? One line per array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fastest way is to manually serialize the data.

An easy way to do this is by creating a FileStream, and then wrapping it in a BinaryWriter/BinaryReader.

You have access to functions to write the basic data structures (`numbers`, `string`, `char`, `byte[]` and `char[]`).

An easy way to write a `int[]` (unneccesary if it's fixed size) is by prepending the length of the array with either an int/long (depending on the size, unsigned doesn't really give any advantages, since arrays use signed datatypes for their length storage). And then write all the ints.

Two ways to write all the ints would be:
1. Simply loop over the entire array.
2. Convert it into a `byte[]` and write it using `BinaryWriter.Write(byte[])`

These is how you can implement them both:

```
// Writing
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(...));
int[] intArr = new int[1000];

writer.Write(intArr.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < intArr.Length; i++)
    writer.Write(intArr[i]);

// Reading
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(...));
int[] intArr = new int[reader.ReadInt32()];

for (int i = 0; i < intArr.Length; i++)
    intArr[i] = reader.ReadInt32();

// Writing, method 2
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(...));
int[] intArr = new int[1000];
byte[] byteArr = new byte[intArr.Length * sizeof(int)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(intArr, 0, byteArr, 0, intArr.Length * sizeof(int));

writer.Write(intArr.Length);
writer.Write(byteArr);

// Reading, method 2
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(...));
int[] intArr = new int[reader.ReadInt32()];
byte[] byteArr = reader.ReadBytes(intArr.Length * sizeof(int));
Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArr, 0, intArr, 0, byteArr.Length);
```

I decided to put this all to the test, with an array of 10000 integers I ran the test 10000 times.

It resulted in method one consumes averagely 888200ns on my system (about 0.89ms).
While method 2 only consumes averagely 568600ns on my system (0.57ms averagely).

Both times include the work the garbage collector has to do.

Obviously method 2 is faster than method 1, though possibly less readable.

Another reason why method 1 can be better than method 2 is because method 2 requires double the amount of RAM free than data you're going to write (the original `int[]` and the `byte[]` that's converted from the `int[]`), when dealing with limited RAM/extremely large files (talking about 512MB+), though if this is the case, you can always make a hybrid solution, by for example writing away 128MB at a time.

Note that method 1 also requires this extra space, but because it's split down in 1 operation per item of the `int[]`, it can release the memory a lot earlier.

Something like this, will write 128MB of an `int[]` at a time:

```
const int WRITECOUNT = 32 * 1024 * 1024; // 32 * sizeof(int)MB

int[] intArr = new int[140 * 1024 * 1024]; // 140 * sizeof(int)MB
for (int i = 0; i < intArr.Length; i++)
    intArr[i] = i;

byte[] byteArr = new byte[WRITECOUNT * sizeof(int)]; // 128MB

int dataDone = 0;

using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream("data.dat", FileMode.Create))
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
{
    while (dataDone < intArr.Length)
    {
        int dataToWrite = intArr.Length - dataDone;
        if (dataToWrite > WRITECOUNT) dataToWrite = WRITECOUNT;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(intArr, dataDone, byteArr, 0, dataToWrite * sizeof(int));
        writer.Write(byteArr);
        dataDone += dataToWrite;
    }
}
```

Note that this is just for writing, reading works differently too :P.
I hope this gives you some more insight in dealing with very large data files :).

Answer (score 6):

If you've just got a bunch of integers, then using JSON will indeed be pretty inefficient in terms of parsing. You can use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` to write binary files efficiently... but it's not clear to me why you need to read the file every time you create an object anyway. Why can't each new object keep a reference to the original array, which has been read once? Or if they need to mutate the data, you could keep one "canonical source" and just copy that array in memory each time you create an object.

Comment: +1 for "Why can't each new object keep a reference to the original array"

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to create a byte array from an array of integers is to use Buffer.BlockCopy

```
byte[] result = new byte[a.Length * sizeof(int)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(a, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
// write result to FileStream or wherever
```

If you store the size of the array in the first element, you can use it again to deserialize. Make sure everything fits into memory, but looking at your file sizes it should.

```
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(@"...");
int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer,0);
var result = new int[size];
Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, result, result.length);
```

Binary is not human readable, but definetely faster than JSON.